# How to strip away letters from string?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to strip away all letters in a string, which are not numeric. Preferably a solution made with Regular Expressions or something. And in C#. 
How to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Regex:

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\D+", "");
```

`\D` is the complement of `\d` - matches everything that isn't a digit. `+` will match one or more of them (it usually works a little better than one by one).

Using Linq (on .Net 4.0):

```
str = String.Concat(str.Where(Char.IsDigit));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "ab123123abc"
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"[\w]", "");
```

Referenced from 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/844skk0h.aspx

Comment: `[\w]` is redundant, you don't need a the character class. `\w` is exactly the same. However, `\w` includes letters and digits (and an underscore), so you end up with special characters and spaces.

Answer (score 0):

i rather like to use the not `^`  like `^\d` or `^[0-9]`

```
string resultString = null;
try {
    resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"[^\d]+", "");
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Comment: Well, that's basically the same, but probably better known. The `try/catch` block isn't needed, the only possible exception is if `subjectString` is `null`, which you better check. You will not get `ArgumentException` for this pattern - it is correct `:)` However, that should be "`[^\d]` or `[^0-9]`"

Answer (score -1):

```
string result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace("text to look for stuff", "pattern", "what to replace it with")
```

Comment: Umm okay? How is this useful? How does regex work? How do you mysteriously use this 'pattern' thing? And how does this answer the question at all?

Comment: My assumption was simply that he didn't know how to call a regex replace in c# rather than wanting exact code to do it. After reading the other answers I realized my answer was wanting but thanks for pointing out that I'm wrong.