# Strip out numbers from a string

Tags: python, regex, string

We have a bunch of strings for example: `c1309`, `IF1306`, `v1309`, `p1209`, `a1309`, `mo1309`.
In Python, what is the best way to strip out the numbers? All I need is: `c`, `IF`, `v`, `p`, `a`, `mo` from above example.

Comment: Why is this simple question upvoted so much o_O ? Also one could just search and use the "reverse" solution of this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3062742).

Comment: @HamZa Simple questions are more likely to be upvoted because they can be easily and quickly observed by all users, including those not even familiar with the language.

Comment: @jamylak sad enough, a little bit jealous to be honest ...

Comment: @HamZa this is nothing... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python/931095#931095

Comment: @jamylak hahahaha I shall learn python !

Comment: @HamZa it's the bikeshed problem.

Answer (score 27):

You can use `regex`:

```
>>> import re
>>> strs = "c1309, IF1306, v1309, p1209, a1309, mo1309"
>>> re.sub(r'\d','',strs)
'c, IF, v, p, a, mo'
```

or a faster version:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\d+','',strs)
'c, IF, v, p, a, mo'
```

`timeit` comparisons:

```
>>> strs = "c1309, IF1306, v1309, p1209, a1309, mo1309"*10**5

>>> %timeit re.sub(r'\d','',strs)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.23 s per loop

>>> %timeit re.sub(r'\d+','',strs)
1 loops, best of 3: 480 ms per loop

>>> %timeit ''.join([c for c in strs if not c.isdigit()])
1 loops, best of 3: 1.07 s per loop

#winner
>>> %timeit from string import digits;strs.translate(None, digits)
10 loops, best of 3: 20.4 ms per loop
```

Comment: Better use `re.sub(r'\d+','',strs)`, though, for increased  efficiency.

Comment: @TimPietzcker thanks, never knew about that.

Comment: @TimPietzcker If numbers are only decimal then does `re.sub(r'[0-9]+','',strs)` improve speed **??**

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Probably not or at least not significantly, unless you compile the regex using `re.UNICODE`.

Answer (score 22):

```
>>> text = 'mo1309'
>>> ''.join([c for c in text if not c.isdigit()])
'mo'
```

This is faster than regex

```
python -m timeit -s "import re; text = 'mo1309'" "re.sub(r'\d','',text)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.99 usec per loop
python -m timeit -s "import re; text = 'mo1309'" "''.join([c for c in text if not c.isdigit()])"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.42 usec per loop
python -m timeit -s "from string import digits; text = 'mo1309'" "text.translate(None, digits)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.42 usec per loop
```

but `str.translate` as suggested by [@DavidSousa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16849154/1219006):

```
from string import digits
text.translate(None, digits)
```

is always the fastest in stripping characters.

Also `itertools` supplies a little known function called `ifilterfalse`

```
>>> from itertools import ifilterfalse
>>> ''.join(ifilterfalse(str.isdigit, text))
'mo'
```

Comment: Is `join` with a list comprehension faster than `join` with a generator expression?

Comment: For large strings they are almost equivalent.

Comment: @Blender http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/846892

Answer (score 13):

I think the string method `translate` is more elegant than joining lists etc.

```
from string import digits # digits = '0123456789'
list1 = ['c1309', 'IF1306', 'v1309', 'p1209', 'a1309', 'mo1309']
list2 = [ i.translate(None, digits) for i in list1 ]
```

Comment: `from string import digits` was better (not sure why you changed it). This is the fastest way and may be arguably more elegant in Python 2, but in Python 3 it looks like: `text.translate(str.maketrans('', '', digits))`

Comment: +1 but you could use list comprehension to make it even more elegant.

Comment: @jamylak I changed it just to look more clear.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the simplest, and will probably be the fastest too.

```
>>> import string
>>> s = 'c1309, IF1306, v1309, p1209, a1309, mo1309'
>>> s.translate(None, string.digits)
'c, IF, v, p, a, mo'
```

Note: interface of `str.translate` was changed to use a mapping in python3, so here is the 3 version

```
s.translate({ord(n): None for n in string.digits})
```

Or a more explicit alternative:

```
m = str.maketrans('', '', string.digits)
s.translate(m)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
strings = ['c1309', 'IF1306', 'v1309', 'p1209', 'a1309', 'mo1309']
stripped = [''.join(c for c in s if not c.isdigit()) for s in strings]
```

Answer (score 1):

*If* all the strings you are dealing with *end* with a number you can, *literally*, `strip` the number:

```
>>> strings = ['c1309', 'IF1306', 'v1309', 'p1209', 'a1309', 'mo1309']
>>> [s.strip("0123456789") for s in strings]
['c', 'IF', 'v', 'p', 'a', 'mo']
```

If you want to remove the digits *only* at the end of the string use `rstrip`. If the digits may appear inside the string then this method wont work at all.

Comment: +1. This is probably all that the OP needs. You could also replace `0123456789` in your solution with `string.digits`

Answer (score 0):

**use slice notation if the numbers length is fixed and position not in the middle of string.**

```
NUM_LEN = 4
stringsWithDigit = ["ab1234", "cde1234", "fgh5678"]
for i in stringsWithDigit:
   print i[:-NUM_LEN]
```

**any thing else**

```
import re
c = re.compile("[^0-9]+")
print c.findall("".join(stringsWithDigit))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+
```

It will just take consecutive alphabets `from start` and neglect all the other stuff in string.

No replacement will be required.